# How do you make all the <h> elements inside an <a> element change color on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My code is:

```
<div class="something">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <h1>hello</h1>
        <h2>world</h2>
        <h3>again!</h3><br/>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Basically I need all the `<h>` elements and the `<p>` element to change color at the same time on hover of the `<a>` tag.

I've tried:

```
.navbar-brand *:hover{
     color:red;   
}
```

but this only changes color on hover of each individual element, not all of them at the same time.

I should also mention because it might be crucial, that the navbar-brand class is a bootstrap class.

Comment: why not `.navbar-brand:hover`?

Comment: Put the :hover on the whole div rather than the elements inside?

Comment: yup, @Satpal you are right..

Comment: that doesn't work for some reason, it just makes the individual elements change color, not all of them :/

Comment: Actually, @Satal is correct.  That works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like following snippet.

```css
.navbar-brand:hover h1, 
.navbar-brand:hover h2, 
.navbar-brand:hover h3, 
.navbar-brand:hover h4, 
.navbar-brand:hover h5 {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="something">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <h1>hello</h1>
        <h2>world</h2>
        <h3>again!</h3><br/>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the correct css:

```
.navbar-brand:hover {
   color:red;   
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t4o0uffm/1/

Answer (score 0):

directly target the `a.navbar-brand:hover` instead of targeting child elements